# Character Moving off screen in Python / PyGame despite setting boundaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, navigation, maze

Creating a game where a maze is randomly generated and the player must navigate from the top left to the bottom right of the maze.

I have tried many things to stop my character going off-screen but it still doesn't work.
When already on the boundary of the screen the code works as intended and the character cannot continue moving off screen. However, if already moving then the character continues moving off the screen until the movement key is released where the character is then teleported back on to the screen where it should be. Additionally, I need to add boundaries to the maze walls as well but this is my current problem.

```
import pygame
import numpy
import sys
import csv
import random
from datetime import date

pygame.init()

done = False
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

cols = 10
rows = 10

width = 600
height = 600
wr = width/cols
hr = height/rows

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
pygame.display.set_caption("Maze Generator")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Spot:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.f = 0
        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.neighbors = []
        self.visited = False
        self.walls = [True, True, True, True]

    def show(self, color=BLACK):
        if self.walls[0]:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, color, [self.x*hr, self.y*wr],       [self.x*hr+hr, self.y*wr], 2)
        if self.walls[1]:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, color, [self.x*hr+hr, self.y*wr],    [self.x*hr+hr, self.y*wr + wr], 2)
        if self.walls[2]:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, color, [self.x*hr+hr, self.y*wr+wr], [self.x*hr, self.y*wr+wr], 2)
        if self.walls[3]:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, color, [self.x*hr, self.y*wr+wr],    [self.x*hr, self.y*wr], 2)

    def show_block(self, color):
        if self.visited:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [self.x*hr+2, self.y*wr+2, hr-2, wr-2])

    def add_neighbors(self):
        if self.x > 0:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.x - 1][self.y])
        if self.y > 0:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.x][self.y - 1])
        if self.x < rows - 1:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.x + 1][self.y])
        if self.y < cols - 1:
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.x][self.y + 1])


grid = [[Spot(i, j) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        grid[i][j].add_neighbors()

current = grid[0][0]
visited = [current]
completed = False


def breakwalls(a, b):
    if a.y == b.y and a.x > b.x:
        grid[b.x][b.y].walls[1] = False
        grid[a.x][a.y].walls[3] = False
    if a.y == b.y and a.x < b.x:
        grid[a.x][a.y].walls[1] = False
        grid[b.x][b.y].walls[3] = False
    if a.x == b.x and a.y < b.y:
        grid[b.x][b.y].walls[0] = False
        grid[a.x][a.y].walls[2] = False
    if a.x == b.x and a.y > b.y:
        grid[a.x][a.y].walls[0] = False
        grid[b.x][b.y].walls[2] = False


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, hr-2, wr-2)
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
        self.colour = (255, 0, 0)
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        self.left_pressed = False
        self.right_pressed = False
        self.up_pressed = False
        self.down_pressed = False
        self.speed = 5

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.colour, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
            self.velX = -self.speed
        if self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
            self.velX = self.speed
        if self.up_pressed and not self.down_pressed:
            self.velY = -self.speed
        if self.down_pressed and not self.up_pressed:
            self.velY = self.speed

        self.x += self.velX
        self.y += self.velY

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, hr-2, wr-2)


def readMyFiles():
    questionsAndAnswers = []
    correctAnswers = []

    with open('questions.txt', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            questionsAndAnswers.append(row)

    return questionsAndAnswers


def game(questions, answers, correctAnswers):
    score = 0
    counter = 0
    numberOfQuestions = len(questions)
    while not counter == numberOfQuestions:
        print(questions[counter])
        print(answers[counter])
        userAnswer = input('\nWhat is the correct answer?\n')
        if userAnswer == correctAnswers[counter]:
            print('Well done! That is correct.')
            score += 1
        else:
            print('Better luck next time, that is not correct.')
        counter += 1

    return score


def shuffleSplit(qna):
    random.shuffle(qna)
    questions = []
    answers = []
    correctAnswers = []
    for q in qna:
        questions.append(q[0])
        correctAnswers.append(q[1])
        del q[0]
        random.shuffle(q)
        answers.append(q)

    return (questions, answers, correctAnswers)


def exportScores(score, ):
    with open('scores.txt', mode='a') as scores:
        scores = csv.writer(scores, delimiter='\t')

        today = date.today()
        dateFormat = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

        scores.writerow([dateFormat, score])


player = Player(2, 2)


while not done:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    if not completed:
        grid[current.x][current.y].visited = True
        got_new = False
        temp = 10

        while not got_new and not completed:
            r = random.randint(0, len(current.neighbors)-1)
            Tempcurrent = current.neighbors[r]
            if not Tempcurrent.visited:
                visited.append(current)
                current = Tempcurrent
                got_new = True
            if temp == 0:
                temp = 10
                if len(visited) == 0:
                    completed = True
                    break
                else:
                    current = visited.pop()
            temp = temp - 1

        if not completed:
            breakwalls(current, visited[len(visited)-1])

        current.visited = True
        current.show_block(WHITE)

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            grid[i][j].show(WHITE)
            # grid[i][j].show_block(BLUE)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            questionsAndAnswers = readMyFiles()
            questions, answers, correctAnswers = shuffleSplit(questionsAndAnswers)
            score = game(questions, answers, correctAnswers)
            exportScores(score)
            print('\nYour score is', str(score))
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and completed:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.left_pressed = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.right_pressed = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.up_pressed = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.down_pressed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.left_pressed = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.right_pressed = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.up_pressed = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.down_pressed = False
        player.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

        if player.x <= 2:
            player.left_pressed = False
            player.x = 2
        if player.y <= 2:
            player.up_pressed = False
            player.y = 2
        if player.x >= width-(wr-2):
            player.right_pressed = False
            player.x = width-(wr-2)
        if player.y >= height-(wr-2):
            player.down_pressed = False
            player.y = height-(wr-2)

    player.draw(screen)
    player.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I have tried using player.clamp_ip(screen_rect) and creating a screen rectangle but this also doesn't work. I have tried checking for going off-screen using player.rect.x rather than player.x but still doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The player moves even if the key is held down, but the keyboard events only occur once when a key is pressed or released. You need to do the collision test in the application loop and not in the event loop:

```py
while not done:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # [...]

    #<--| INDENTATION

    player.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

    if player.x <= 2:
        player.left_pressed = False
        player.x = 2
    if player.y <= 2:
        player.up_pressed = False
        player.y = 2
    if player.x >= width-(wr-2):
        player.right_pressed = False
        player.x = width-(wr-2)
    if player.y >= height-(wr-2):
        player.down_pressed = False
        player.y = height-(wr-2)

    player.draw(screen)
    player.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes so much sense and I can't believe I overlooked it for so long. I'm annoyed it was that simple but happy it's not finally fixed. Appreciated.